# loaded postgres with data from an sql file but, hasura is not picking up the tables from the database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, docker-compose, haproxy, hasura

What would cause Hasura not being able to pick up the contents of postgres? I have a table called users and Hasura is saying that it does not recognize that name for a table. I have no way of going into the console due to HAPROXY configuration issues with Hasura console.

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis
    container_name: db1
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    network_mode: "host"
  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.0.1
    container_name: hasura1
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
    - "postgres"
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/postgres
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/postgres
      ## enable the console served by server
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      ## enable debugging mode. It is recommended to disable this in production
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: "true"
      ## uncomment next line to set an admin secret
      ## HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: 
volumes:
  db_data:
```

when I go inside the database docker, and check the database, the tables are there from when I imported them

```
              List of relations
 Schema |       Name       | Type  |  Owner   
--------+------------------+-------+----------
 public | blockList        | table | postgres
 public | commentReactions | table | postgres
 public | comments         | table | postgres
 public | eventBanned      | table | postgres
 public | eventInvites     | table | postgres
 public | eventPermissions | table | postgres
 public | events           | table | postgres
 public | friends          | table | postgres
 public | interestTags     | table | postgres
 public | membership       | table | postgres
 public | messageReactions | table | postgres
 public | messages         | table | postgres
 public | music            | table | postgres
 public | scoreCard        | table | postgres
 public | spaceInvites     | table | postgres
 public | spaces           | table | postgres
 public | spatial_ref_sys  | table | postgres
 public | swipeDislikes    | table | postgres
 public | swipeLikes       | table | postgres
 public | swipeOptions     | table | postgres
 public | threadUsers      | table | postgres
 public | userSettings     | table | postgres
 public | users            | table | postgres
```

I am running a backend that I built in dart, it connect just fine on my mac.

Here is my query basic test query.

```
query {
  users(limit: 1) {
    id
  }
}
```

Here is my HAPROXY settings (no clue if this is right):

```
    bind *:8088
    server hasura localhost:8080 check
```

Comment: Really no way to answer this question in it's current form. More information needed: 1) How are you connecting to the database? 2) What is the query you are running? 3) Is the table name in the database UPPER or MixedCase?

Comment: i am using a config file, it's def connecting, i'll post the config in the question. i double checked the capitalization and it's fine, i had this working locally on my mac so it's none of that. right now i am using docker on ubuntu with postgresql + postgis + hasura

Comment: "due to HAPROXY configuration issues with Hasura console." - how HAPROXY is involved in all that? Can you stop it or can you run hasura on other port and try to connect to this port?

Comment: that was my speculation, i could be wrong, what i did do was used a ssh tunnel and that allowed me to access the console, from there i was able to apply the migrations. i still can't access the console directly from the outside, which is fine since i did the work around. but yeah it must be something else then because i turned off HAPROXY and it still would not let me in, i turned off the firewall as well and nothing, must be a configuration issue with my docker-compose file or something